# Searching for hints on how to implement immutable data structures in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, immutability

I'm wondering how to implement immutable data structures in C++ (or C). I'm searching for a book or paper (or a relatively simple and documented implementation) on the subject and I haven't managed to find one for now so I decided to ask for hints.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for Persistent data structures (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure)? If so, you can take a look at immutable collections in .net for some other hints as well (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx)

Comment: I don't know if you are still looking for the answer, but it's a good idea to look at how Rich Hickey implement immutable data structure in clojure using java.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may take an idea from another languages. For example in Java and C# immutability implemented following way. Instead of creating "mutators" (functions that "mutate" objects' state), we create functions that return new "changed" instance:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(int i)
   : i_(i)
   {}

   int GetI() const {return i_;}
   Foo SetI(int i) const {return Foo(i);}
private:
   const int i_;
};
```

Comment: That exactly what I meant by "immutable", but what I'm searching for hints on how to efficiently implement immutable collections (eg: Clojure collections), particularly how to share part of the structure to avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: @fokenrute I think that is the real question, sharing the part of the  immutable structure. In garbage collected languages that is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

You can either declare objects as const like:

`const std::string x("My Const String");`

This is a common way of using the const keyword to make an object immutable.

If you know you have an object that you do not want to allow anything to be changed in and this should be
part of the behavior of every instance of that object, you can make an object with all const members.

```
class Immutable
{
   public:
   Immutable() :z(10), y(20) 
   {

   }

   Immutable(int zVal, int yVal) : z(zVal), y(yVal) 
   {

   }

   int getZ() const;
   int getY() const;

   private:
   const int z;
   const int y;
};
```

Note that you must set the values of const members within an initialization list. (which you should be using anyway as best practice)

Answer (score 0):

`const` is your friend - objects with all data members `const` are hard to alter.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Phoenix Framework.](http://boost-spirit.com/distrib/spirit_1_8_3/libs/spirit/phoenix/index.html)

Phoenix extends the concepts of FP to C++ much further. In a nutshell, the framework opens up FP techniques such as Lambda (unnamed functions) and Currying (partial function evaluation).

So it goes beyond simple immutable structures, but I assume that is the direction you're headed.

Comment: Does it also allow structure sharing?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Declare a `struct` as follows:

```
struct Immutable
{
private:
    Immutable& operator =(const Immutable& other);
};
```

This locks down the assignment operator. Now make sure the struct has no `public` or `mutable` member variables and that all its public methods are `const`:

```
public:
    int get_quux() const;
    void foo(int bar) const;
```

And you have something very close to an immutable type. Of course, the lack of `sealed`/`final` in C++ means that someone can derive a less immutable type from yours anyway.

Comment: Immutable doesn't mean non-copyable.  You don't have to worry about the object being copied.

Comment: You're absolutely right, one only has to worry about the object being assigned to. Answer updated accordingly. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "immutable data structure".

If you mean, a type where variables of that type can't be assigned to otherwise modified, then see the other answers here (removing access to assignment operator, using `const`, or simply having a reference or `const` data member).

If you mean, a type where *values* of that type can't be modified,e.g. like a Java or C# or Python string, but where variables of that type still can be assigned, then it's more tricky. Your best help there may be `boost::intrusive_ptr` to manage an internal mutable state. The reason for `intrusive_ptr` as opposed to e.g. `shared_ptr` is that `intrusive_ptr` allows more optimizations, one of which is crucial for e.g. "immutable strings", namely, constructing such a beast from a literal with no dynamic allocation at all.

I'm not aware of any general framework for doing the latter kind of "immutable data structure" in C++.

So, it seems that you've put up a good idea! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a project on Github called gorgone, which contains a C++ implementation of PersistentVector (based on Rich Hickey's Java implementation in Clojure) and RRBVector (based on more recent work by Phil Bagwell).

The maintainer of that project is no longer pursuing it, but I am.  See my fork here:  https://github.com/sandover/gorgone

Answer (score 0):

I can't help to recommend this article [Immutable C++ stack - thoughts and performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26080/immutable-c-stack-thoughts-and-performance), the code review and answer is really awesome!

Also, for getting started with `persistent data structures` or `functional data structures` in C++, read this post [Functional Data Structures in C++: Lists](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2013/11/13/functional-data-structures-in-c-lists/).